# xhttp.send() get error POST 500 (Internal Server Error)

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, xmlhttprequest

when trying to send the data to the server the error POST 500(internal server Error ) display
here is my form

```
<form class="input-group" id="f">
    <div class="form" style="display :-webkit-inline-box;">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="comment" placeholder=" Comment ">
        <span class="input-group-btn">
                 {{--<input class="btn btn-default" type="button" onclick="loadDoc()" value="Comment!">!--}}

            <input class="btn btn-default" type="button" onclick="loadDoc()" value="Comment!">
             </span>
    </div>
    <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
</form><!-- /input-group -->
```

and this is the javascript code

```
    function loadDoc() {
        var dd = document.getElementById('f');
        var d = [];
        r=0;
        for (var i = 0; i < dd.elements.length; i++){
            if(dd[i].type == "text") {
            d[r] = dd[i].value;
            r++;
            }
    }
        var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        var url = "/place/{{$place->id}}";
        var params = "data="+d;
        xhttp.open("POST", url , true);
        xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                var json = JSON.parse(this.response);
                console.log(json);
            }
        };
        xhttp.send(params);
    }
```

i am trying to make a comment

Comment: Is the javascript code in a JS file? You can't use laravel blade syntax inside a `.js` file, it won't parse it. So the call to your controller will literally call `/place/{{$place->id}}` instead of what you might think it calls. Should be easy to see whats going on in your console.

Comment: the javascript code not in a file its in the view @JeremyHarris

Comment: What does the browser console say in the response? With Laravel, you should see the error there.

Comment: this is the error 
 POST "the url of the file want to open " 500 (Internal Server Error)
and the url is correct
@JeremyHarris

Comment: HTTP STATUS 500 means there is something wrong on the server side code. It is not your javascript nor the form. The issue is where you have /place/{{$place->id}} points to. ( either controller or model ). You may look at laravel logs to see what is wrong.

Comment: With this method your `_token` field is not being added to the XHR request. If your `protected $routeMiddlewareGroup` array utilizes `\App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,` then the request will fail. Also, your javascript implementation seems to be attempting to re-create what the `FormData()` object does. Try `var d = new FormData(document.getElementById('f'));`

Answer (score 0):

If you don't plan to use CSRF Token, than go to the

```
App/Http/Kernel.php
```

And delete or comment line

```
\App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class
```

And your profilem is solved... otherwise add _token param in that xhttp request...